# Does the robot's 6-cost development counters count towards Galactic Federation?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

During solo-play, if the robot successfully places `Galactic Federation`, do each of the 6-cost counters earned by the robot also earn the additional 2 VPs from `Galactic Federation`?

This is from the `Gathering Storm` expansion to `Race For The Galaxy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

> Add the robot's VP chips and tableau VPs, scoring each 6-cost development card or counter as 6 or 9 VPs, depending on the selected game difficulty.

Galactic Federation, as well as any other such development card, will always count for 6 or 9 VPs.  Don't try to count based on the contents of the tableau.

Comment: Oops!  I wonder how many games I would have won if I had read that rule more carefully.  It also looks like the 6-cost development *counters* count as a card in the robot's tableau of 12 cards when meeting end-game-conditions.